# How do I find my network IP address, netmask, and gateway info?

Tags: networking, info

I'm trying to make my IP address static as I hear it fixes slow browsing issues.

When I click on connection information under the networking menu of the gray taskbar, it tells me about the IP address, subnet mask, and DNS, but nothing about the gateway.

I would like to know if there's a terminal command to find the information.

Comment: The default route is another name for gateway, and is listed there, but you don't "make" your IP static unless it is a local address assigned by your router. Normally your ISP assigns you a dynamic address, and that is what you have to use. Rather than try some random voodoo you should try asking a question about the real problem you are having and hopefully get a proper fix.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I have this command as an alias for "ipconfig" (up to 14.04):

```
nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep IP4
```

An example listing is:

```
IP4-SETTINGS.ADDRESS:                   192.168.1.110
IP4-SETTINGS.PREFIX:                    24 (255.255.255.0)
IP4-SETTINGS.GATEWAY:                   192.168.1.1
IP4-DNS1.DNS:                           208.67.222.222
IP4-DNS2.DNS:                           208.67.220.220
```

If `eth0` doesn't work, you may need to use `eth1`, `eth2`, ... depending on your configuration.

**EDIT: 2/8/16**

Note that this only works in versions before v15.04 (or possibly before v14.10; I have v14.04). For newer versions, you can use this:

```
 nmcli dev show eth0
```

Comment: Because my subnet mask was in `DHCP4.*`, I needed `nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep -e IP4 -e subnet_mask`

Comment: Also make a note this will not work in cases where the system devices are controlled by `/etc/network/interfaces` / the kernel; for example, my laptop has a static IPv4 of `10.50.1.10` with a netmask of `255.255.255.0` (or `/24` if you prefer CIDR prefixes), which is used in a static-LAN environment, and is configured through `/etc/network/interfaces` - this is listed as "unmanaged" if you have Network Manager on your system, so `nmcli` will never show the configurations in place there.

Comment: @ThomasW. - Thanks for that info, but TBH, I personally think that there is such a thing as too much information.  The question was pretty simple, and I gave a simple answer using what information I knew would work.  I'm really not knowledgeable enough to "support" your information; also, I think anyone who is would know their gateway address and would not be trying to find out this information.

Comment: as of 16.04 this does not show subnet information on a separate line but rather appends it to the IP4.ADDRESS[1]: field (in my case, 192.168.1.2/24).

Comment: In Debian nmcli `list` and `iface` are not found.  Instead use:  `nmcli dev show eth0 | grep IP4`

Answer (score 28):

You can use `ifconfig`, it will show your inet address (IP) and mask.

For the gateway, issue the `ip route` command and take note of the default route.

[image: ifconfigandiproute]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Is "ip route" mean Default Gateway?

Answer (score 9):

[This website](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/protocols/ip-classes.html) explains how the `network` and `broadcast` addresses can be calculated via a netmask and a computer's ip address. To simplify that article: `network` is the  lowest possible address in the range of ip addresses left over from the netmask. `broadcast` is the highest numbered ip address in that range. The "*range of ip addresses left over from the netmask*" is known as the local network.

"*The network*" typically means everyone above you, including the Internet. To get to "*the network*", the `network` address is used. In reality, most people call "the network" anything with ethernet cables that can talk to each other.

Example: your ISP gives you info to type into a wireless router: a static IP address of `99.1.81.209` and your netmask is `255.255.255.224`. Now you're wanting to set up an ubuntu firewall and need to set up your public interface:

```
Calculate network IP address:
255.255.255.224 -> last octet = E0
 99.  1. 81.209 -> last octet = D1
Logical AND the mask and your ip: 
E0 & D1 = C0 = 192
--> network = 99.1.81.192

Calculate broadcast address:
255.255.255.224 : E0 -> there are 1F = 31,
-> broadcast = 99.1.81.192 + .31 = 99.1.81.223
```

The other way...

```
Calculate broadcast address:
255.255.255.224 -> last octet = E0
 99.  1. 81.209 -> last octet = D1
Hosts' IPs = 1F 
Logical OR the hosts ips with your ip:
1F | D6 = DF = 223 
--> broadcast = 99.1.81.223
```

Often, you'll see networks described with a /. Here's this network:

```
255.255.255.224 is the netmask, add up the "1" bits:
 8 + 8 + 8 + 3  = 27
so "this network" gets /27 notation
and can be described as 99.1.81.192/27
```

Answer (score 5):

In versions before 15.04 there used to exist `nm-tool` utility.

From `man nm-tool`:

```
NAME
       nm-tool - utility to report NetworkManager state and devices

SYNOPSIS
       nm-tool

DESCRIPTION
       The nm-tool utility provides information about NetworkManager, device, and wireless networks.
```

This small utility would interface nicely with the Network Manager and produce a report with appropriate information on each line, which was quite simple to parse with text processing utilities. Sample output:

```
$ nm-tool | sed -ne '/^  *IPv4/,/^$/p'
  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.42.178
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.42.129
```

[Rinzwind's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/617072/295286) on the related question has cited the [changelog](https://launchpad.net/~mariusko/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-backports/+sourcepub/4693622/+listing-archive-extra) for Network Manager package, which explains that it has been dropped upstream and superseded by `nmcli`. It should be noted, however, that `nmcli` before and after 15.04 differs with several command-line arguments. Here's alternative to the above:

```
$ nmcli dev show | grep 'IP4\.ADDRESS\|IP4.GATEWAY'
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.101/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
```

With `nmcli` information is shown in accordance with each interface, i.e. there's set of lines for one interface, then separated by a blank line another set of lines and so forth.

Another alternative that one can use would be `ip` command which  is preferred nowadays to `ifconfig`. According to [pilona's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93461/85039) and [Gilles's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93499/85039) answers on [Difference between 'ifconfig' and 'ip' commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93412/85039), Linux kernel and networking features have advanced forward but `ifconfig` and the package to which it belongs haven't evolved in a long time, and that's why we have `ip` utilities. For getting the addressing information on specific interfaces `ip -o -4 addr` can be used and `ip route` can be used for getting routing/gateway information.

Answer (score 3):

`nm-tool` will also do the job.

```
$ nm-tool
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

....

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.110
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             208.67.222.222
    DNS:             208.67.220.220
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 3):

Quick update to this old question. With newer versions of Linux you probably have the `ip` command now which replaces `ifconfig`.

```
ip -o -f inet addr show | awk '/scope global/ {print $2,$4,$6}'
```

Will show something like this:

```
$ ip -o -f inet addr show | awk '/scope global/ {print $2,$4,$6}'
eth0 192.168.1.169/24 192.168.1.255
wlan0 192.168.1.115/24 192.168.1.255
```

or something like this on the newest versions of Linux:

```
$ ip -o -f inet addr show | awk '/scope global/ {print $2,$4,$6}'
enp0s25 192.168.1.191/24 192.168.1.255
```

The 3 return values are:

- The network interface name
- The IP address for that interface followed by the subnet mask (`/24`)
- The broadcast IP address for that interfaces subnet

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to get an overview of my network configuration:

`ip addr` , this show you an overview of your NIC settings
`route -n` , it gives you a nice overview of where your traffic is going.
`cat /etc/resolv.conf` for dns info
`cat /etc/hosts` for preloaded hostnames

Changing to a static IP address will not affect your browsing speed though. The only difference between static and dynamic is that on static, you always have the same IP address. With dynamic, you will be assigned a "random" IP address by your DHCP server when you connect to the network. Once you have been assigned an IP address, it will behave exactly the same way as if you had assigned yourself a static IP addresss.