# Why nm-tool is no longer available in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: network-manager

Why is the nm-tool command line tool not available in Ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: You mean `nmcli`?

Comment: @Jos no, this is really about nm-tool.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Please read the 2015-01-27 [changelog](https://launchpad.net/~mariusko/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-backports/+sourcepub/4693622/+listing-archive-extra) for network manager. A snippet form all the changes ...

> network-manager (0.9.10.0-1) unstable; urgency=medium
>
> - New upstream release.
> - Exclude libtool .la files from list-missing.
> - Update symbols files.
> - Update Build-Depends as per configure.ac.
> - Build and install nmtui, a curses-based interface for easier console
>     operation.
> - Install new device plugins.
> - **Stop installing the nm-tool binary which was dropped upstream as it has  been replaced by the much more powerful nmcli tool.**

The name of what you want is  [nmcli](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/nmcli.1.html).

Besides that there is a new tool call `nmtui`:

> network-manager (0.9.10.0-1) unstable; urgency=medium
>
> - New upstream release.
> - Exclude libtool .la files from list-missing.
> - Update symbols files.
> - Update Build-Depends as per configure.ac.
> - Build and install nmtui, a curses-based interface for easier console
>     operation.

From the manual page for nmtui:

> nmtui — Text User Interface for controlling NetworkManager
>
> ```
> nmtui [edit | connect | hostname] [...] 
> nmtui-edit [connection-id | connection-name] 
> nmtui-connect [connection-name | connection-uuid | device-name | Wi-Fi-SSID] 
> nmtui-hostname
> ```

Comment: In addition, they added a new tool `nmtui`.

Answer (score 6):

`nm-tool` was used to report network manager's status and information about interfaces, providing a convenient summary of network connections and your connection status.  However my understanding is that as of 15.04 Ubuntu is switching to `systemd` service manager, and NetworkManager from previous versions doesn't work quite well with `systemd`, hence now NetworkManager has changed to the one very similar to NetworkManager used in Fedora ( which by the way uses `systemd`  ).

What you can do is to use `nmcli` options to give you a convenient summary of just like `nm-tool` use to do. In particular use `nmcli device show <interface>`. This is the same as `nmcli dev list <iface>` on the previous version.  `<interface>` part is optional, and can be used only if you need info about specific interface, such as `wlan0` or `eth0`.
To view info for alll interfaces, use `nmcli dev show`. There is a lot of material , so you can pipe it all into `less` like so     :   `nmcli dev show | less`

And here is a little one-liner I wrote to give general overview of system connections: `nmcli dev show  | awk '/GENERAL.DEVICE/,/GENERAL.DRIVER/;/GENERAL.CONNECTION/;/IP4.ADDRESS/,/IP4.DOMAIN/'`

Sample output:

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           802-3-ethernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     not connected
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           802-11-wireless
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8187SE Wireless LAN Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8180
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = ******/24, gw = ******.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             208.67.222.222
IP4.DNS[2]:                             208.67.220.220
IP4.DNS[3]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          ******.edu
```

`nmcli dev wifi` will list available access points. Note, that `dev` and `device` are used interchangeably.

Comment: I had to use `nmcli device wifi list` or I would get the error `Error: 'dev' command 'list' is not valid.`

Comment: @mchid that's strange. What version of Ubuntu you're using ?

Comment: this is on 15.04

Comment: @mchid OK, let me fix the answer a little bit . . . .In 15.04 `dev ` doesn't take `list` as argument , it's replaced by `show`.

Comment: Yes, `dev` seems to work fine when  `wifi` is specified.

Comment: @mchid Ok, I've updated my answer. Don't know how, but I messed up and wrote `list` option everywhere in the original, instead of `show`. Also, I'm  planning to write a script that mimics the behavior of `nm-tool`. Would you be interested in that ?

Comment: Sure, I always like new scripts. I've just been using an alias for `nmcli -f IN-USE,BSSID,SSID,SIGNAL,BARS,CHAN,FREQ,SECURITY dev wifi list`

Answer (score 2):

As of recent versions, nm-tool is no longer included as part of the network-manager package.

**For 15.04+**:

You can, however, extract nm-tool from the 14.04 version of network-manager. Here's how it can be done.

It should be noted that there may have been security updates since posting this. You can visit http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/network-manager to verify the version listed below is the most recent version available.

Run the following commands:

```
cd
mkdir nm-tool; cd nm-tool
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.1_amd64.deb
ar xvf *
tar xvf dat*
sudo mv ./usr/bin/nm-tool /usr/local/bin/
cd ..
rm -r nm-tool
```

The following commands should now be available:

`nm-tool`.

Comment: `nm-applet` and `nm-connection-editor` are for the GUI. It seems a bad idea to mess with both of them. `nm-online` is provided by 15.04's Network Manager, so there's no reason to mess with that either. Also, use the `dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile` command for extracting files from .deb files. I'd use something like: `dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile network-manager_*.deb | tar -xC / ./usr/bin/nm-tool`

Comment: @muru thanks, I've updated but will have to try the `--fsys-tarfile` later, thanks. Also, I mostly used `nm-tool` for listing bssids, ssids, and strengths of local signals and `nmcli` can be used to do this with: `nmcli -f BSSID,SSID,SIGNAL,BARS dev wifi list` anyhow.

Comment: @Maxwel, edits shouldn't fundamentally change the code in a post. Please write a comment instead.