# wifi still sleeping when resume

Tags: gnome, network-manager, nmcli

When I put my desktop in hybernate and then put it back on the wifi is gone. It is simular to the problem described  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617067/why-nm-tool-is-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu-15-04). But to fix it you have to run a command `sudo nmcli nm sleep false`. But the `nm` thing is not working anymore. It has been removed from nmcli (Describe [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617067/why-nm-tool-is-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu-15-04)). So what could you do to fix it?

I am using ubuntu gnome 4.2

Comment: Does your wireless come back with`sudo service network-manager restart`?

Comment: @chili555 yes it does. I could use that but it would be better to get de WiFi out of the sleeping mode instead of restarting al networking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit  /etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. A new empty file will open. Add the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Local system resume actions
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart network-manager.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Proofread carefully twice, save and close the text editor.

Now do:

```
sudo chmod +x  /etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service
```

And next:

```
sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service
```

I suggest you reboot. Test and let us hear your report.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot. It did gave an gtk warning when I did `sudo gedit  /etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service`. But I do not now exactly what it was. And after the reboot I could't reproduce it. Is it right to use `sudo` or is it better to use 'gksudo'

Comment: Probably `gksudo`, but if it works then it's all good! I will edit the answer for the benefit of the searchers.

Comment: @chili555 I have the same problem, I followed your instructions but the last command `sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service` returns 'command not found'

Comment: @bruco Please start your own new question and include the results of: `lsb_release -a` I wonder if your Ubuntu version is older and doesn't use *systemd*.

Comment: @chili555 here is my question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/903141/wifi-not-working-after-sleep-suspend

Answer (score 1):

Another solution similar to the nmcli one Tristan T referenced in the question (without nm, which is no longer an option as Tristan mentioned):

```
nmcli radio wifi on
```

I used [Owais Lone](https://askubuntu.com/users/214/owais-lone)'s [answer to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04/608897#608897) to enable automatic resume of wifi after suspension for my laptop (a Dell Precision) on 16.04 LTS.

I created /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
      nmcli radio wifi off && nmcli radio wifi on;;
esac
```

followed by a `sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi` to make the file executable.

In case you're wondering about the double semicolons or the solitary close parenthesis like I was, see http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html -- that's just how the case syntax works.

Answer (score 1):

For me worked

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
    resume|thaw)
      nmcli radio wifi off && nmcli radio wifi on;;
esac
```

followed by a sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi

Also user can try if the first fails.

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
    post|resume|thaw)
      nmcli radio wifi off && nmcli radio wifi on;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer in this thread did not work for me, not did any of the alternate solutions. I had to add the following service file as `/etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Restart Network Manager at resume (after suspend)
After=suspend.target
After=hibernate.target
After=hybrid-sleep.target
[Service]
Type=oneshot
# note: the following also unloads iwlwifi
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/modprobe -r iwldvm
# note: the following also loads iwldvm
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/modprobe iwlwifi
[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

and then enable with `sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service`

As a backup while testing the above, I created a bash script with the following

```
#!/bin/bash
echo {MY_PASSWORD} | sudo -S modprobe -r iwldvm
echo {MY_PASSWORD} | sudo -S modprobe iwlwifi
echo {MY_PASSWORD} | sudo -S service network-manager restart
notify-send "Wifi: reloaded."
exit
```

And tied it to a custom keyboard shortcut.