# No network devices available after resuming from suspend on 16.04

Tags: networking, suspend

I have the same problem as described in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1555775. My card is the Killer 1535 and I can't confirm the issue with the wired connection.

The one-time solution given by the poster

```
sudo su  
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

works for me as well. However, I don't know how to make it automatic after resuming from suspend. I tried making a script named alienware_pci_rescan in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` with the code

```
#! /bin/sh  

# This script rescans the PCI bus after resume from suspend to fix  
# broken WiFi, wired ethernet, and the card reader on the Alienware 15 R2.

case $1 in  
     resume|thaw)  
        echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:1c.4/rescan  
 echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:1c.5/rescan  
 echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:1c.6/rescan  
        ;;  
esac
```

provided by Andy Barry (abarry-gmail) but it doesn't work. I also tried to find out how shall I change the numbers after `.../devices/` in the above script by looking at the information from `lspci`, but to no avail as I am not sure where to look. Any help?

Comment: Does the device spring back to life with: `sudo service network-manager restart` ? If so, please check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/748113/wifi-still-sleeping-when-resume/748130#748130

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I tried this - it doesn't solve the issue