# Create laptop as Access Point

Tags: wireless-access-point

I'm sorry i'm newbie at Ubuntu, i'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with my laptop Asus N43SL

I want to share my wireless internet from my laptop as Access Point, why? because i using android smartphone, so i can't create ad-hoc wireless

i know there's so many thread here about creating Access Point but sorry i really not get it..

I'm following this site to create it

[How to set up a wi-fi hotspot with an Ubuntu laptop (access point mode)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323335/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-with-an-ubuntu-laptop-access-point-mode)

but when i start the hotspot, terminal always show

```
Starting Wireless Hotspot...
```

please is there a script to do this or an application to do it easier?
give me the link if there is

Comment: Try and follow these instructions, in case of any issues, post here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html

Comment: Thank You, it help so much, i dont know that ap-hotspot for Ubuntu 14.04 is buggy.

Comment: Cool. Anytime. I hope everything is fine now.

Comment: One last question about ap-hotspot, how do i know my laptop ip? @Parto

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/197628/how-do-i-find-my-network-ip-address-netmask-and-gateway-info