# The 'proper' way to get ONLY my eth0 netmask via CLI in Ubuntu 18.04 on VPS?

Tags: command-line, networking, server, vps, ifconfig

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/197643/880404) and many other tutorials throughout the web, `ifconfig` will list lots of fascinating and useful information. And, that seems the standard way to find out stuff like my netmask.

But, for scripting, I need *only* the netmask itself for `eth0`; and `man ifconfig` was unhelpful with this question.

I am using a VPS, so I don't have control of my netmask; I need to *find out* what it has been set to.

*(Note: While I need `eth0`, some machines might have another, say `eth1` or `ens3`, which would also be useful.)*

- I do ***not*** need the entire line the netmask is in:

`inet 111.222.333.444  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 111.222.555.666`

- I ***want to avoid*** a "hackdoor" method, like getting `netmask 255.255.255.0` then running `sed "s/netmask //"` because stuff can change—*unless an expert says so*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is what you need (note this will not work on Ubuntu 16.04):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
IFACE='eth0'
ifconfig | grep -A 7 "$IFACE" | sed -nr 's/^.*netmask\s([0-9\.]+)\s\sbroadcast.*$/\1/p'
```

In the first line the name of the network interface is assigned as value of the variable `$IFACE` - this is useful for scripting, otherwise you can use `grep -A 7 'eth0'`.

On the second line the output of the command `ifconfig` will be piped to the `grep` command, where the option `-A 7` will output the following 7 lines after the line with the matched string/regexp. The output of that command will be piped to `sed`.

Within the `sed` command:

- the regular expression `^.*netmask\s(.*)\s\sbroadcast.*$` will match to the whole line, from the beginning `^` to the end `$`, that contains some characters `.*` and the "keywords" *`netmask\space`*, *`[0-9\.]+`* and *`\s\sbroadcast`* in that exact order;
- that line will be substituted (`s/old/new/`) with the content of the first capture group [`(.*)`->`\1`], where the regexp `[0-9\.]+` will match to the strings that are consisted of digits end dots;
- the option `-r` (or `-E`) will enable the extended regular expressions, which, in this case, will allow us to use the round brackets freely;
- the option `-n` with combination of the flag `p` with output only the matched line and will preserve the rest output of `sed`.

---

Here is an extended example that will parse the names of all network interfaces and will do similar as the above command for each of them:

```bsh
for IFACE in $(ifconfig | sed -nr 's/(^[a-z0-9]+):.*/\1/p'); do \
    echo -en "${IFACE}:\t"; ifconfig | \
    grep -A 7 "$IFACE" | \
    sed 's/  broadcast.*$//' | \
    sed -rn 's/^.*netmask (.*)$/\1/p'; \
done
```

Sample output of the above command executed on a virtual machine with Ubuntu 18.04:

```bsh
$ for IFACE in $(ifconfig | sed -nr 's/(^[a-z0-9]+):.*/\1/p'); do echo -en "${IFACE}:\t"; ifconfig | grep -A 7 "$IFACE" | sed 's/..broadcast.*$//' | sed -rn 's/^.*netmask (.*)$/\1/p'; done
ens33:  255.255.255.0
lo:     255.0.0.0
```

Comment: Yep, that's it! You Rock!